# Como enviar requisição no formato Timestamp: yyyyMMddHHmmssffff usando Postman?

Tags: javascript, data, postman, momentjs

Preciso usar o Postman para enviar uma requisição à API e no cabeçalho preciso enviar a data no formato `yyyyMMddHHmmssffff`.

Tentei usar o Moment.js dessa maneira, mas parece não funcionar:

```
const moment = require('moment');
pm.environment.set("timestamp", moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmssffff'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Na [documentação do Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) podemos ver que para as frações de segundo usa-se `S` (a letra "S" maiúscula), então o formato ficaria assim:

```js
console.log(moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmssSSSS'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Na mesma documentação vemos que a letra `f` não está na lista de formatos reconhecidos.

Esse é um ponto importante ao usar diferentes linguagens e API's de formatação de datas. As letras correspondentes a cada campo (ano, mês dia, hora, minuto, segundo, etc) não são necessariamente as mesmas, cada uma usa o seu próprio "padrão" (basta comparar o Moment.js com [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) e [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), por exemplo). Por isso é importante sempre consultar a documentação.

Comment: Entao, acredito que assim ele retorne nos SSS os milisegundos, mas pelo que parece aqui no meu problema de algum jeito eu preciso de algo menor que o milisegundo, em C# existe uma função que dá exatamente o que preciso, porém nao sei como colocar esse resultado em minha requisição.


Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff"));

Comment: @PauloVitor O `Date` do JavaScript tem precisão de milissegundos, então se quiser 4 casas decimais, a última sempre será zero. Se o serviço aceita somente 4 casas decimais, use SSSS. Se não for esse o problema, por favor edite a pergunta colocando mais detalhes

Answer (score 0):

Para chegar no formato que você precisa é possível utilizar apenas os métodos do [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) como o exemplo abaixo mostra:

```js
const a = new Date();
const yyyy = a.getFullYear();
const MM = (a.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
const dd = a.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const hh = a.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const mm = a.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const ss = a.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const ffff = a.getMilliseconds().toString().padStart(4, '0');

console.log(`${yyyy}${MM}${dd}${hh}${mm}${ss}${ffff}`);
```

Para passar um valor no cabeçalho:

```
const echoPostRequest = {
  url: 'https://postman-echo.com/post',
  method: 'POST',
  header: '<seu_cabeçalho>:<valor_data_formatada>', // << add seu valor aqui
  body: {
    mode: 'raw',
    raw: JSON.stringify({ key: 'this is json' })
  }
};

pm.sendRequest(echoPostRequest, function (err, res) {
  console.log(err ? err : res.json());
});
```

Comment: Entao, acredito que assim ele retorne nos ffff os milisegundos e complete com zero a esquerda, mas pelo que parece aqui no meu problema de algum jeito eu preciso de algo menor que o milisegundo, em C# existe uma função que dá exatamente o que preciso, porém nao sei como colocar esse resultado em minha requisição. Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff"));

Comment: @PauloVitor dê uma olhada nesse código JS que faz igual em .NET: https://gist.github.com/marlun78/1351171/5c10ff750547808a7c72d1953fefb5430c4829a5

Answer (score -1):

Creio que seja a formatação YYYYMMDDHHmmssffff que você colocou que está incorreta. De acordo com seu código, ficaria assim:

```js
const moment = require('moment');
pm.environment.set("timestamp", moment().format('YYYYMMDDhhmmss'));
```